# Frame Buffer couldn't be constructed: incomplete attachment error on nexus 7

Tags: java, libgdx

So I am running into an issue where I cannot load my game onto the nexus 7 because of the error stated previously. I read online that this is because the device can't use the Format class or something like that but I find this funny because I ran the game on the device with the framebuffer earlier without any problems. The game runs perfectly fine on the nexus 5.

**EDIT**

Code breaks here in the initialization process.

```
buffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, (int) gameWidth, (int) gameHeight, false);
```

Here is a part of the stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: frame buffer couldn't be contructed: incomplete attachment.
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.Framebuffer.build(FrameBuffer.java:171)
```

Here is the Framebuffer:171 code

```
if (result == GL20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT)
throw new IllegalStateException("frame buffer couldn't be constructed: incomplete attachment");
```

Comment: A minimal example demonstrating the problem might make this answerable.

Comment: Sure hold on one sec.

Comment: Ok, I put in the code that breaks and part of the stack trace. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you sure `gameWidth` and `gameHeight` are correct for your device?

Comment: Oh sir, you may be right. I was thinking it would need the whole game world size and not the screen devices size but I may be wrong. I will reply again when I get the result.

Comment: Yep, I am an idiot you have fixed my problem. Could you explain why it was breaking the code though? Just curious.

Comment: The program was crashing because `FrameBuffer` expected the dimensions of the screen, and you passed it some dimensions that were not those of the screen.

Comment: @PandaPajama Pajama can the dimensions be 1024X1024 ?